# Use pm2 with pkg

Tags: node.js, exe, pm2

I have taken help from [this site](https://dev.to/jochemstoel/bundle-your-node-app-to-a-single-executable-for-windows-linux-and-osx-2c89) and created a `.exe`(an executable) for my node app. But, in case of some errors, it just vanishes. I used to get on with it by using `pm2`, but now that I need to use an executable, I have used [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg), to create its `.exe` file.

Is there a way to run this using `pm2` just on double clicking it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can stop a top level error from closing the running program. It's more a OS feature than a nodeJS one.

You will need to catch all errors and manage them properly.

The easier way to do that (but not the cleanest) would be wrap the entry point in a try catch function and relaunch it from the catch when an error arise.

Comment: True that... The `try-catch` part I've already done. Just wanting to know if I can use pm2 with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per my knowledge PM2 restarts once it encounters errors, there is also a way to watch for changes in the folder structure. Once there is an error and your server is about to restart at that particular time use the package to build the .exe file and then start the server.

In the following, if you want to pass any arguments then use **--node-args** else don't use

```
pm2 start app.js --name "You App Name" --node-args="-r dotenv/config" --watch
```

And then in your **app.js** file do the following

```
const pkg = require('pkg');

//here use the package to build the .exe file

//here start the server
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/438

```
npm install pkg -g
npm install pm2 -g;
sed -ri -e '/dt.toString/d' -e '/PM2_BANNER/d' /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js;
pkg -o /pm2 --targets linuxstatic `which pm2`;
/pm2 --version
```